# wso2 ESB how to check if dataservice returns no records

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB ,in a sequence ,  I am calling a dataservice and expects some rows.If the rows exists , it should go further . If no records are found  , I want to stop the sequence from proceeding further. When no records are found , there is no logic to execute.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while configuring a data service in DSS you need to check the option "return request status", So this will provide you a response if there is no records in the table, as it's XML based so you will get root element as a return response from DSS.
In you sequence you can add a filter condition to check if the response contains and data or not

Comment: thats great.. so its bascially Filter mediator?

Comment: Yes you can use a filter mediator where you mention the xpath , and if the xpath is not matching then it goes to else condition where you can use loopback mediator.